# Altering the results of collection before binding it to a listbox

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, linq-to-xml

I have a simple Linq to XML query that i run and the results are bound to a `listbox` (via a `collection`). What i can't figure out is how to alter the result before binding them, for example. I have the following code:

```
 XElement xmlEvents = XElement.Parse(e.Result);
 lstb.ItemsSource = from GetEvents in xmlEvents.Descendants("e2event")
     select new GetEvents
     {
         eventid = GetEvents.Element("eventid").Value,
         eventtime = GetEvents.Element("eventtime").Value
     };
```

`eventtime` returns a linux time stamp, i have a little method that converts this into a datetime stamp. So how would i go about converting to this before binding to the `listbox`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the simplest approach would be to change your projection:

```
XElement xmlEvents = XElement.Parse(e.Result);
lstb.ItemsSource =
            from GetEvents in xmlEvents.Descendants("e2event")
            select new GetEvents
            {
                 eventid = GetEvents.Element("eventid").Value,
                 eventtime = ConvertTime(GetEvents.Element("eventtime").Value)
            };
```

(Where `ConvertTime` is your method.)

Note that if this is an integer value, you could get LINQ to XML to perform the numeric conversion for you:

```
XElement xmlEvents = XElement.Parse(e.Result);
lstb.ItemsSource =
            from GetEvents in xmlEvents.Descendants("e2event")
            select new GetEvents
            {
                 eventid = GetEvents.Element("eventid").Value,
                 eventtime = ConvertTime((long) GetEvents.Element("eventtime"))
            };
```

Comment: my method ConverTime wants a double so i didnt as above but used double instead of long. I just get an error saying "Cannot convert type string to double" An example i'm using; e2eventstart = ConvertFromUnixTimestamp((double)GetEvents.Element("e2eventstart").Value), thanks

Comment: @Nathan: You didn't copy my example closely enough - note that in the second example where I'm using the explicit conversion to `long` I'm *not* using the `Value` property. I'm converting the `XElement` itself.

Comment: your 100% correct, i missed the last bit. Really sorry about that and thanks for your help :)

Comment: @Nathan: No problem. It's worth looking at the options around conversions, including to nullable values, in case the element isn't present. LINQ to XML is lovely :)

Comment: must admit, it seems very clean and compact yet pretty powerful!